# Tell Mocha where to look for test files

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

How can I tell `Mocha` where to look for my test files? My test files dont reside in the standard project root `./test` folder. My test sit in `Modules/.*/Tests/`.

I've attempted to use the `--grep` command line argument but I have a feeling this argument looks for test NAMES not for test FILE NAMES.

> mocha --grep `Modules\/.*\/Tests`

The above command gives the error:

> Warning: Could not find any test files matching pattern: test
>   No test files found

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to match not only directory but also its files . Besides, do no need grep , use only `--` :

```
mocha -- Modules/**/Tests/*.js
// or `mocha -- Modules/Tests/*.js` (I am not sure because you didn't give the project hierarchy )
```